# emplace_back with pointer and unique pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, unique, unique-ptr

In relation to `someFunctionOne` and `someFunctionTwo`.

Is the end result still the same when each is emplaced into the map ?

Does the pointer get upgraded to a smart pointer ?

```
struct MyStruct {
        int x = 0;
    };

std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> m_map;

void someFunctionOne(int id, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>& myStruct){
    m_map.emplace(id, std::move(myStruct));
}

void someFunctionTwo(int id, MyStruct * myStruct){
    m_map.emplace(id, myStruct);
}

int main()
{
    someFunctionOne(452, std::make_unique<MyStruct>());
    someFunctionTwo(10, new MyStruct);

    m_map.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the second one can lead to memory leak if `emplace` throws OOM exception while extending map. Other than that they are equivalent. I would use the first one, as it is explicit about ownership.

Comment: The first one doesn't actually compile.  You need an rvalue reference or to pass by value.  You can and should at least try things out before posting here.

Comment: @aschepler smells like the infamous MSVC extension that binds lvalue references to rvalues...

Comment: @Quentin Can you explain please ?

Comment: @user3220058 there's a C++ extension that is enabled by default in MSVC, that allows your code to compile even though it's not valid C++. You can use the [`/Za`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) flag to disable extensions.

Comment: @Quentin This is disabled and the code still runs, can you explain why the code is wrong or why aschelper cannot run it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the pointer get upgraded to a smart pointer ?

The correct term is [Implicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). But yes, that is what would happen in this line:

```
m_map.emplace(id, myStruct);
```

This is because unique_pointer has a single value constructor which has the signature:

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

This is what would be called to convert the pointer to a unique_ptr.